# ADOdb CopyFromRecordset to Excel range not moving to next record

Tags: c#, adodb, excel-interop, recordset

I am populating an ADOdb recordset to Excel using C# interop.

```
while (!rs.EOF)
  {
    Excel.Worksheet xlMainWs = xlList.Find(x => x.Name.Equals("tMain"));
    ((Excel.Worksheet)xlMainWs).Select();
    Excel.Range mainc1 = xlMainWs.Cells[refStartRow + 1, refStartCol];
    Excel.Range mainc2 = xlMainWs.Cells[refStartRow + 1, refEndCol];
    Excel.Range mainRng = (Excel.Range)xlMainWs.get_Range(mainc1, mainc2);
    mainRng.ClearContents();
    mainRng.CopyFromRecordset(rs, 1);
    rs.MoveNext();
  }
```

While I can populate the recordset to the excel range, the problem is it keeps populating the first row from the recordset. I tried putting:

```
rs.MoveNext();
```

but it's still populating the first row of the recordset.

I did the same in Excel VBA, the loop will move the record cursor to next record.

Why doesn't this work the same in C#?

Comment: Where did you put `rs.MoveNext();`?

Comment: [code]
mainRng.CopyFromRecordset(rs, 1);

rs.MoveNext(); **right here**

Comment: That's important, so [edit] the question to show it there. That way viewers can see that it's in the right place and they can look elsewhere for explanations.